# APPLICATION FAILED TO START in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have the default spring aplication and throws this warn and stopped working
don't have a controller and service it's just a demo app

```
WARN 9256 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
11:00 ERROR 9256 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Comment: Can you share your properties file?

Comment: Where did you get the demo app and does the README specify anything about creating a database?  Looks like your `application.properties` file doesn't detail anything about a datasource, but your spring project is configured to expect one.

Comment: the properties file has only server.local=8080 , and demo app i created in spring initializr

Comment: my pom file has this dependencies : spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-devtools , spring-boot-starter-test

Comment: Thanks it was just for check if spring works in my work computer , i just delete the spring data dependency and works , but when i have to use spring data dependency i will check what you told me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spring data as a dependency, You need to specify a datasource url to connect to a database in your application.properties file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks , it was just for check if spring works in my work computer , i just delete the dependency and works , but when i have to use spring data dependency i will do what you told me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your **application.properties** file data will be filled correctly or not.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_database_name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```